# Cómo enviar mas de un parámetro por GET en flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

```
  Future<List> ListadoPortaPapeles() async {
    var url="http://201.182.xxx.xx/pedido_flutter/ListadoPortaPapeles.php?dato1="
        +widget.lista[widget.index]['id_pro']+"&dato2="+
        widget.lista[widget.index]['id_cat']+"";
    print(url);
    final response= await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Lo vengo haciendo de esta forma, pero me arroja el siguiete error:
**FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 2)**

Si le envio un parametro no hay problema, lo envia normal, pero no de esta forma.

Adicional a esta pregunta lo que nesecito es enviar unos datos que tengo en una lista que traigo desde mi BD, esta lista la tengo en una clase **ElementoLista extends StatelessWidget** intente enviarle por post, que cuando le de tap en la lista al boton aceptar me envie estos datos, pero si instancio variables por fuera de esta clase no las agarra, y si llamos los elemtos de esta lista por fuera de la clase tampoco los agarra.
esta es mi lista.

```
class ElementoLista extends StatelessWidget {

  final List lista;

  ElementoLista({ required this.lista });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: lista == null ? 0 : lista.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, posicion) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {

              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(

                    builder: (BuildContext context) => DetallesUsuario(
                        posicion,
                        lista
                    ),
                  )
              );
            },

            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                      Row(children: [Text("REF: "+lista[posicion]['id_ped'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),)],),
                      Row(children: [Text(lista[posicion]['nom_cli']+" "+lista[posicion]['ape_cli'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),)],),
                      Row(children: [Text(lista[posicion]['fecha'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),)],),
                      Column(children: [
                       /* Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color: Colors.pink,
                          size: 24.0,
                          semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                        )*/
                      ],)

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

no se si sea clara mi duda. Pero les pregunto como enviarian los datos de esta lista por peticion http, bien sea por get o post.

Aca dejo el codigo que tengo en mi body:

```
 Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<List> (
                future: obtenerUsuarios(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? ElementoLista(
                    lista: snapshot.data!,
                  )
                      : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: abre lo que imprime print(url); en un navegador y revisa el contenido en https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al error:

> FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 2)

Estás tratando de obtener una respuesta json, pero esta tiene un formato incorrecto, probablemente el json que obtienes como respuesta es incorrecto y al llamar `json.decode(response.body)` se genera el error.

La url que se imprime cárgala en el navegador, ya que es un GET y revisa que obtiene, el json debe estar formateado correctamente, puedes usar jsonlint.com